# How to perform a Distinct Sum using MDX?

Tags: mdx, mondrian

So I have data like this:

```
Date       EMPLOYEE_ID   HEADCOUNT   TERMINATIONS
1/31/2011        1            1             0 
2/28/2011        1            1             0
3/31/2011        1            1             0
4/30/2011        1            1             0
...
1/31/2012        1            1             0
2/28/2012        1            1             0
3/31/2012        1            1             0

1/31/2012        2            1             0
2/28/2011        2            1             0
3/31/2011        2            1             0
4/30/2011        2            0             1    

1/31/2012        3            1             0
2/28/2011        3            1             0
3/31/2011        3            1             0
4/30/2011        3            1             0
...
1/31/2012        3            1             0
2/28/2012        3            1             0
3/31/2012        3            1             0
```

And I want to sum up the headcount, but I need to remove the duplicate entries from the sum by the employee_id.  From the data you can see employee_id 1 occurs many times in the table, but I only want to add its headcount column once.  For example if I rolled up on year I might get a report using this query:

```
with member [Measures].[Distinct HeadCount] as
          ??? how do I define this???
select { [Date].[YEAR].children } on ROWS, 
       { [Measures].[Distinct HeadCount] } on COLUMNS 
       from [someCube]
```

It would product this output:

```
YEAR    Distinct HeadCount
2011           3
2012           2
```

Any ideas how to do this with MDX?  Is there a way to control which row is used in the sum for each employee?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Distinct HeadCount] AS
    Sum(NonEmpty('the set of the employee ids', 'all the dates of the current year (ie [Date].[YEAR].CurrentMember)'), [Measures].[HeadCount])
```

If you want a more generic expression you can use this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Distinct HeadCount] AS
    Sum(NonEmpty('the set of the employee ids', 
                 Descendants(Axis(0).Item(0).Item(0).Hierarchy.CurrentMember, Axis(0).Item(0).Item(0).Hierarchy.CurrentMember.Level, LEAVES)),
        IIf(IsLeaf(Axis(0).Item(0).Item(0).Hierarchy.CurrentMember),
            [Measures].[HeadCount],
            NULL))
```

Comment: Would this not be a simple distinct-count aggregation of the employee_id column?  I want to sum the value in the headcount field for each unique employee id ignoring the duplicate entries.  I don't follow how this would do that exactly.  Also bear in mind rolling up on year was just an example.  I'd like my calculated measure to not take in what dimension I'm rolling up on so I can use it in any query I create.

Comment: Can you explain this better?  I have a bounty that I'd like to award if this is truly a solution.  But, the first suggestion doesn't seem any different that a distinct-count.  Can you explain why either of these work?